# Trying to Make WIFI connection on android 4.1 jellybean

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

New Nextbook tablet Android 4.1 Jellybean.  trying to make WIFI connection.  Ensured that SSID is enabled. Password entered.  Device says its obtaining IP address, then avoided poor internet connection.  How to I fix this?

Comment: See: [“Avoided poor Internet connection” even though signal strength, speed is great](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46513/11251), [What does “avoided poor Internet connection” mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22848/11251). (This question might not be a 100% duplicate, because apparently the presence of the “Avoid poor Internet connection” setting is manufacturer-specific.)

Answer (score 1):

Your router may have a pairing button that you need to press. If it does, it must be pressed  the first time you attempt to make a connection. Be close to the router. Turn off Wi-Fi, and hit "on" again. Go to `Settings > Wireless networks > Wi-Fi`.

My router is a Cisco Linksys X2000, and I had problems too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and all online guides failed, i eventually downloaded kingroot and it fixed it when i did "optamize" in that program and "activate game mode".  If you have any battery saving apps or use kingroots Purify sub-app, do not "optimize battery" as one of the things it does is affect the wifi as that is a battery drain, so switch off any "optamize battery" features in any apps.
This worked for me.